# Создать заглушку на загрузку контента Jquery

Tags: jquery, javascript

Добрый день мастера JS, подскажите как сделать корректно:

```
 - Если JQuery загружен, работает, страница только начала загружаться -> показать DIV
 - Когда весь DOM загружен полностью и много картинок по 1.5мб тоже -> скрыть DIV
```

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы сделал [комбинированное решение](http://jsfiddle.net/2z7Zy/), т.к. событие onLoad может произойти достаточно поздно, либо вообще никогда в силу разных причин:

```
jQuery(function ($){
    // DOM Ready!

    var imagesQueue = [];

    $.each(document.images, function (i, img){
         if( !img.complete ){
             var dfd = $.Deferred();
             $(img).one('load abort', dfd.resolve);
             imagesQueue.push(dfd);
         }
    });

    $.when.apply($, imagesQueue).done(function (){
        // Все изображения "загружены"
        $('#loading').hide();
    });
});
```