# Создать заглушку на загрузку контента Jquery (v2.0)

Tags: jquery, javascript

Милый человек @RubaXa [ВОТ ТУТ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/243318/javascript-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-jquery) посоветовал такой код на "заглушку" когда грузится контент:

```
jQuery(function ($){
    // DOM Ready!

    var imagesQueue = [];

    $.each(document.images, function (i, img){
         if( !img.complete ){
             var dfd = $.Deferred();
             $(img).one('load abort', dfd.resolve);
             imagesQueue.push(dfd);
         }
    });

    $.when.apply($, imagesQueue).done(function (){
        // Все изображения "загружены"
        $('#loading').hide();
    });
});
```

К сожалению нашлись недочеты который самостоятельным копанием я устранить не смог:

- в IE9 работает через раз, т.е. бывает что #loading так и не скрывается (скрипты работают);
- Функция срабатывает до того как загружен весь контент(!) заметил что после скрытия loader'а подгружаются ещё background-image (менять их на Img с z-index -1 не очень хочется);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну да, всё верно. Она грузит только картинки, которые указаны через img. Если вас это не устраивает, нужно использовать onload, либо писать CSS парсер (который будет работать только с CSS, который лежит на том же домене). По поводу IE9 следует подписаться на `load abort error`, упустил в прошлый раз.

Как видите решение не идеальное, можно попробовать сделать через onLoad, с защитой от "зависания":

```
(function ($){
    var dfd = $.Deferred();

    $(window).on('load', dfd.resolve);

    // Ждем максимум 5 секунд
    setTimeout(dfd.resolve, 5 * 1000);

    dfd.done(function (){
        $('#loading').hide();
    });
})(jQuery);
```